# Typo3 CMS throws Error after successful installation

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

Once I finish installing Typo3 locally on my system using latest xampp on PHP 8 version. Website stops working. Installation gets completed successfully, but once installation is completed, whole website stops working. This is strange. Every time I tried installing latest Typo3 version, 11.5, same issue happens.
[image]

Comment: Check PHP configuration and what PHP error log says?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the kind of installation you're likely missing the correct server configuration. Usually it's done by a `.htaccess` file in the web-root of the installation.
An example `.htaccess` file, which in many installations never even needs adjustments, is located inside your installation, you just have to copy it in the webroot and rename it to `.htaccess`. It's located here:

```
typo3\sysext\install\Resources\Private\FolderStructureTemplateFiles\root-htaccess
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Screenshot, you are using Port 81 (localhost:81).

I suggest using the default Port 80 and "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost" (http://127.0.0.1).
Using Port 81 would need changes in your firewall configuration in many cases.

Additionally, your folder structure seems wrong ("/typo3_src-11.5.12/typo3/login?...").
Your backend should be reachable under "/typo3/" or "/typo3/index.php".

If you are using a legacy installation (without composer), the folder /typo3_src-11.5.12/ should be one level above your web server's document root, as stated here:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-getting-started/main/en-us/Installation/LegacyInstallation.html